# Files actually exists, yet Python shows "no such file or directory" despite using absolute path

Tags: python, file

As can be seen in the following snippets, I have been trying to open a file in Python, the file actually exists, and I am using **absolute** (not relative) path in the code. Yet, as can be seen this stragne error message (***no such file or directory***) keeps poping up annoyingly.

Any ideas?

[image: Files actually exist]

[image: Yet a strange error message keeps poping up]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

the file you are trying to open is **E.srt** but the path in the error message says **E.str**

Comment: How silly I can get! Thanks life saver

Comment: No problem my friend

Answer (score 0):

You typed `E.str` when you meant `E.srt`.